# Python timing between client and server

Tags: python, time, server, client, timing

I am having problems with the python timing. Right now I am creating a game with both a server and client (using twisted). I am trying to measure the time it takes for a packet it come in so I can calculate speed correctly. I have tried using time.time() and time.clock() with the same problem. They are just not reliable.

So what I do is send a movement update roughly every 0.2 seconds. I measured the client sent the packet after 0.202649094381 seconds. The server takes the current time minus the time we last got a packet. However the server says it took 0.19164764274 seconds since it got the last packet. Which doesn't make sense, the server shouldn't be getting packets QUICKER than the client can send them, especially if you factor in native network latency. This seems to happen intermittently (client: 0.202243417922 vs server: 0.20065745487) How can python be that imprecise? I tried time.time() which is suppose to use the system clock and the time.clock() which is supposed to measure CPU clock but both are still not reliable enough. Maybe I am going about this wrong? Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: Your server is measuring time since it last _received_ a packet. If its lower than the client time, doesn't that just mean that the previous packet was delayed a bit. I suspect you'll need to look for trends over multiple cycles. BTW, use `time.time` on linux and `time.clock` on windows. On linux, `time.clock` measures cpu time, not wall time. On windows, `time.clock` is higher resolution.

Comment: That's a good point I didn't consider. However, if the times are constantly off, the trends over time won't help either since everything is going to be off. Currently I am using time.clock since I'm using windows.

Comment: If your server is on a spaceship accelerating towards pluto it would be slower... but for most of us it would be strange indeed for it to be consistently slower. On my linux mint laptop, I'm seeing a resolution of 0.000020 seconds. It would be normal to see jitter on that scale. But if its consistently off over a long period of time, I'd be very puzzled.

Comment: If you are referring to getting the mean speed over time that works for the updates. However, initial movement may still be far over (sometimes as much as an 8% difference). Even if it works out over time, but not initially, and I sample it every so often, then it doesn't solve it's intended function as preventing movement speed hacking.